# Spring - conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-mybatis

The specific exception is:

```
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception;
nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:
Annotation-specified bean name 'myService' for bean class [my.package.ejb.MyService] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [my.package.other.ejb.MyService]
```

Those `MyService` interfaces are not even annotated, they represent EJB 2.0 stateless beans.

My annotation configuration is as follow.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.package")
@MapperScan("my.package")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("...");
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory(final DataSource dataSource) {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sqlSessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("..."));
        return sqlSessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager(final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Might be an incompatibility with `@MapperScan` (from MyBatis) and `@ComponentScan`?

The exception come from the `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` I'm using to Autowire EJB 3.0 fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `MapperScannerConfigurer` says that:

> This class supports filtering the mappers created by either specifying
>   a marker interface or an annotation. The annotationClass property
>   specifies an annotation to search for. The markerInterface property
>   specifies a parent interface to search for. If both properties are
>   specified, mappers are added for interfaces that match either
>   criteria. **By default, these two properties are null, so all interfaces
>   in the given basePackage are added as mappers**.

Basically I was mapping thousands of interfaces as beans. Not cool!
Guys, my fault.